# discord.js - Issues with sending a message

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have a command handler which it's module and constructed like this.

```
module.exports ={
    name: "test",
execute(message, args) {
var yes = client.channels.cache.get('818107649912209438')
yes.send('some message')
}
```

Whenever I try to send a message to a specific channel, The bot returns an error which is;

```
  var yes = client.channels.cache.get("818107649912209438");
                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined
```

And I've been trying to fix this, but no luck. If anyone knows why it doesn't work and would like to help, I'd be thankful.

Answer (score 2):

Your error `'of undefined'` means you are access the channel property through something, but that something is not defined. In this command handler, you are not defining `client`. You have to pass the `client` object as a parameter which you have defined in the main file, like `execute(message,args,client)` and then access the properties or methods of the client.

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is not clear, So I will show you a example on how to handle, I will show code and explanation later.

Formatting:

- Folder

1. **File**

---

- events

1. message.js

```js
// I used message as msg to shorten my code.
const all_requires = require("../settings/settings"); // Exported all requires
const { config, Discord, client } = all_requires; // Imported what I need
module.exports = (client, msg) => {

    if(msg.author.bot || !msg.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return;
    const args = msg.content.split(" ").slice(1);
    const command = msg.content.split(' ')[0].slice(config.prefix.length);
    const cmd = client.commands.get(command); //enmap handler
    console.log(cmd);
    if(!cmd) return;

    cmd.run(msg, args);
}
```

- commands

1. ping.js

```js
module.exports.run = (msg) => {
    msg.channel.send("Pong!");
}
```

- config

1. config.json

```json
{
    "token": "TOKEN-HERE",
    "prefix": "+"
}
```

- settings

1. settings.js

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const fs = require("fs");
const enmap = require("enmap");
const config = require("../config/config.json");
const client = new Discord.Client();

const all_requires = { Discord, fs, enmap, config, client }
module.exports = all_requires;
```

---

index.js

```js
const all_requires = require("./settings/settings");
const { Discord, fs, enmap, config, client } = all_requires;
client.commands = new enmap;

client.once("ready", () => {
    console.log(`${client.user.tag} is Connected.`);
})

fs.readdir("./events/", (err, files) => {
    if(err) return console.error(err);
    files.forEach(file => {
        const event = require(`./events/${file}`);
        let eventName = file.split(".")[0];
        client.on(eventName, event.bind(null, client));
    });
    console.log(`${files.length} Events Loaded.`)
});

fs.readdir("./commands/", (err, files) => {
    if(err) return console.error(err);
    files.forEach(file => {
        let props = require(`./commands/${file}`);
        let commandName = file.split(".")[0];
        client.commands.set(commandName, props);
    });
    console.log(`Loaded ${files.length} Commands.`);
});

process.on('unhandledRejection', err => console.log(err));
client.login(config.token);
```

---

### [Files Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXVPw.png)

As a handlers you need to show me the whole code to know what you're doing to handle commands, you can use either `enmap` [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/enmap) like in the example of that basic code, or use `discord.js` [link](https://discordjs.guide/command-handling/#dynamically-reading-command-files) Handlers to execute the commands, look at `message.js` *Line:8* `client.commands.get()` here we defined the enmap handler, and at *Line:13* for `cmd.run()` we run the commands, using only `module.exports.run` and we defined command handler in `index.js` *Line:3* and we set the commands in *Line:24* inside the `fs` **for loop**.

> -Enjoy Coding.